# JPA with Postgres anomalously writes text in @Lob column as a number

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, lob

I am trying to use a `@Lob` column with a Java `String` type to map its content to `TEXT` inside Postgres.  Here is the relevant entity:

```java
@Entity(name="metadata")
public class Metadata {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    @ColumnDefault(value="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "draft")
    private Boolean draft;

    @OneToMany(cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "metadata")
    private List<Attachment> attachments;

    public void addAttachment(Attachment attachment) {
        if (attachments == null) {
            attachments = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        attachments.add(attachment);
        attachment.setMetadata(this);
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

I have code which creates a new `Metadata` entity based on use input.  I verify manually in IntelliJ debug mode that this entity has the `content` set to its intended value (which happens to be a JSON string).  However, when I check Postgres after running the code, I see this data:

```
my_db=> select * from metadata;
 id | content |       created_on        | draft
----+---------+-------------------------+-------
  1 | 49289   | 2021-04-26 14:21:25.733 | t
(1 row)
```

Note carefully that the strange values `49289` is appearing where we would expect to see a JSON string.  Note that I also verified from the command line that the correct table is what was created:

```
CREATE TABLE scarfon_attachment (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    contents text,
    filename character varying(255),
    scarfon_id bigint NOT NULL
);
```

All the other columns in the entity/table are working as expected.  What could be the problem with the `@Lob` annotation.  For reference, I am running a fairly old version of Postgres (9.2), but it is not that ancient.

Comment: The @Lob annotation uses the dreaded "Large Objects" instead of a proper string. Annotate the column with @String - a `text` column is not a "Lob"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But will `@String` tell the driver to instruct Postgres to use `TEXT`?  Forgive me, you certainly know more about this than I do.

Comment: A `text` column can be used in exactly the same way as a `varchar` column. So yes, JPA should treat it correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first doubt here owed to many sources suggesting multiple ways for creating a `TEXT` column.  For example, [this Baeldung post](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-annotation-postgresql-text-type) suggests using `@Lob` in addition to use a definition with the `@Column` annotation.

As it turns out, `@Lob` is not interpreted the same by all databases.  In the case of Postgres, just using `@Lob` alone will result in Postgres storing the column contents in a *different* table, with the column annotated with `@Lob` just storing an ID for each entry in that table.  While it has been suggested [here](https://shred.zone/cilla/page/299/string-lobs-on-postgresql-with-hibernate-36.html) that also specifying the correct type via the `@Type` annotation can remedy this problem, I decided to go with the second suggestion by the Baledung post, which is using `@Column`:

```java
@Lob
@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String content;
```

This worked fine, and the resulting Postgres table had a `TEXT` definition as expected.  The only potential issue with the above might center around portability to other SQL databases which perhaps do not support a `TEXT` type, or maybe support some alternative.  I did not test beyond Postgres and H2, but in both cases the above was working without issues.

Comment: I had to also remove `@Lob` to make it work

Comment: I had a similar problem and also had to remove @Lob because it was mapping to a Long. Leaving only @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT") works.

Comment: This is not correct, @Lob is not required at all for a postgres database, and if you use it, it will always create a (not referentially guaranteed) reference to the system table `pg_largeobject` instead. IF done as described here, the column will still contain a reference to that table, but as a string instead (which is worse then as a long).

More details are in the comments to the other, correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76711803/11389043

Comment: See for example this post: https://geeknet.me/hibernate-postgresql-the-lob-annotation/

This is correct and provides a solution, and describes the problem a bit more in depth. Unfortunately this stackoverflow answer ranks higher in google

Comment: To be more precise, when I wrote "@Lob is not required at all for a postgres database", I  was just referring to the case as asked (i.e. text data). For other data, postgres provides a set of server-side functions (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/lo-funcs.html#LO-FUNCS-TABLE). @Lob in combination with the postgres driver uses these functions, but this will result in the opaque `oid` int4 column instead of actual data in the source table

Answer (score 0):

When using `@Lob`, Hibernate ORM will expect a column of type `text` in the database with which you can save a text file up to a 1 Gb.

You can avoid using it and it will change the type of the column to `VARCHAR(255)`.
The difference is that you can limit the size of a `VARCHAR` and the default is 255 with ORM, but you cannot limit the size of a `text`.

You can also change the default column type (I think varchar can be as big as 1Gb):

```
@Column(name = "content", columnDefinition = "varchar(500)")
String content
```

So, in the end, which approach to use is up to you. I'm assuming that for big strings `text` is better but you need to evaluate your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my goal is in fact to use `TEXT`, because I want to support larger strings.  255 characters is way too small to be useful for my use case.

Comment: That's the default, but you can change the size. Anyway, my point is that there's nothing wrong with it, it's just the way PostgreSQL saves data of types text.

Comment: I've updated my answer, with an example on how you can change the way the column is defined.

Comment: A varchar can get to 1Gb as well: http://sqlines.com/postgresql/datatypes/text

Comment: I was unable to get `varchar` as defined from the Java code to anywhere near that high.

Comment: OK, I didn't actually try.

Comment: There are a bit more details about it in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980068/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-varcharn-in-postgresql-9-2-and-which-is-best-to

Answer (score 0):

When data is stored in a `LOB` column, it is not stored directly in the regular row data like other columns. Instead, it is stored in a **separate location** in the database, and the row only contains a reference (usually a numeric identifier) to that separate location.

The reason you see numbers like `1124` instead of the real `TEXT` code when you query the database directly is that the actual `TEXT` content is stored in a separate location, and the number `1124` is a **reference (or pointer)** to that location. This is a way to manage and optimize the storage of large data that would not fit well within the regular row data structure.

When you retrieve the data using the application, the JPA will handle the process of retrieving the `LOB` data and mapping it back to the layout field as a string containing the actual `TEXT`.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, Why do you think it's AI?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - After digging in on it a bit more, I'm less inclined to believe that it might be, but are you rewriting the answer using any tool?  That could throw things off.  Also, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425578/11810933) for why I don't go into details on the specifics of your question ;-).  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, From my point of view, why offer something or ask if you are not going to answer the answers - this is not right. It's better then not to start a dialogue at all :)

Comment: Under normal site conditions, we wouldn't be.  We'd simply be flagging answers that we thought were AI-assisted.  However, due to the moderator strike, we're left with this suboptimal "commenting" to give users a heads-up when we think something is AI-based.  Every so often, we're wrong, which is *also* why it's nice to have the Moderation team be a second set of eyes on answers before taking action.  I do hope things can get back to "normal" soon :-).

Comment: However, to be clear, when the Mod team takes action (as they've done on *thousands* of answers), they don't provide the rationale either, for the same reasons I mentioned.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, I noticed that this forum is generally engaged in lawlessness without explaining the reasons - for example, they banned me from creating questions **"just because"**. So for many people, `StackOverFlow` is a forum that **does not follow its own rules** ...

Comment: I don't know the exact circumstances, but question bans are typically *automatic* based on hitting a certain number of "poorly received" (by downvotes or close votes) questions.  Yes, the *algorithm* that handles this is, by necessity, not made public by SE, or users would try to evade it.  There's usually no *"they"* involved in *"they banned"* - It's the way the site works.  I'm not sure we can say that the system isn't following its own rules ;-)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, Then analyze my questions and you will see that they are compiled in accordance with the requirements of the forum "how to ask questions correctly". HOWEVER, there are A LOT of "Explain, I don't understand how it works" questions WITHOUT stating what the person did and such questions are NOT BANNED. Explain why?
For example, the most banal question style is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do/419185#419185

Comment: Often we never really know for sure why people downvote (or not).  I mean, obvious you got a downvote for your "minuses fart" edit on your question, but only a single one before it was rolled back by a moderator.  The others were likely due to a lack of clarity, but I don't know for sure.  There was also one in there that looked like a homework question the way it was phrased - I don't think it was, but some people do downvote things that look like homework.

Comment: The one you linked to, IMHO, is a *very* good question.  It's obviously one that a lot of people search on, with it having been seen 4.4 million times.  Sure, it's *basic* to most people now, but every Python beginner comes across it at some point.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, The fact is that this question was created in VIOLATION of the rules of this forum - the person himself did not look for anything, but immediately went to ask a question. There are thousands of such questions! Another thing is that this question is popular, but it violates the rules of the forum. However, my question does NOT violate forum rules. From this we can conclude that the forum moderators "sit on two chairs" and act according to double standards - like it, then leave it, if you don't like it - ban it. (continued in next comment)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, Consequently, the forum **moderators still LEAVED such moments (such as my questions) without due attention**, and the moderators themselves, it turns out, violate their own rules. What are we talking about now? No one is going to deal with this situation, I'm still banned from creating new questions. **Everything is simple here** - either you unban me (because the questions are asked according to the rules of the forum) or everything remains as it is and the **moderators continue to violate their own rules**. As the saying goes *"less words, more action"*.

Comment: This is the correct answer unfortunately. The accepted answer is wrong and will produce a column in the original table of type "text", but containing a OID (as string) which references the system table pg_largeobject. I know this because we have exactly the same code as in the original question in our service, and I just analyzed that to find out what is stated in this answer.

There is no good documentation on this. In my eyes it's a bug in Spring Data/Hibernate, and this wrong answer here even leads to a wrong resolution. I may post a blog post to hve something to refer to.

Comment: To summarise: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67553059/11389043 is the wrong answer, and what's stated in this answer is correct. It may or may note have been created by an AI, but it is nevertheless correct.

Comment: Original code from our codebase (2024):
  @Lob
  @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
  private String payload;

  @Lob()
  @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
  private String errorMessage;

Columns are `TEXT` according to the schema, contents are numbers (for example, `301352'`), and these numbers (as strings) refer to the system table `pg_largeobject`